# OCUnit - Break on test case failure?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ocunit

When debugging test case failures it would be very useful if the execution would automatically break upon test case failure, so that I could directly investigate the failure. So essentially a break point that triggers when an assertion fails.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions how can you achieve that, to list a few:

1. Add a symbolic breakpoint to `[SenTestCase failWithException:]`
2. Overriding `failWithException:` in a `SenTestCase`
3. Use your own testing macros, which you can break after the fail

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer earlier. When I got your answer I had already fixed all the failing test cases, but now I had some failures to investigate and I can report that at least the first solution works. Thank you.